# How to use the str.translate() method from Python in objective c?

Tags: python, ios, translate

So the title explains most of it. I'm starting to work on Objective c for iOS and I haven't found out if there is a way to use a translate()-like in Objective c.

This is the program I've used for it in python.:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from string import maketrans   # Required to call maketrans function.

intab = "aeiou"
outtab = "12345"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

str = "this is string example....wow!!!";
print str.translate(trantab);
```

Output:

> th3s 3s str3ng 2x1mpl2....w4w!!!

Comment: `str` is a builtin name in Python; don't overwrite it.

Comment: His example comes straight from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm. I also assume he knows it's built-in based on the title.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, there is no builtin method for like `translate()`. (You could, however, get the exact same function in Objective C by using PyObjc, look it up)

You could try doing something with [`replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on a NSMutableString or write a function yourself, with a loop that looks at every character in string, checks if it has to be replaced, and if so, replaces it with the right character. (Because that is what the `translate()` function does, right?)

Comment: [I've posted `translate()`'s algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12764045/4279) to illustrate what it does.

Answer (score 0):

[`translates()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5e319fdab563/Objects/bytesobject.c#l1523)'s algorithm (an inplace variant) in pure C is:

```
char *input; // input C string

for (char *s = input; *s; ++s) 
  *s = trantab[(unsigned char) *s];
```

where `trantab` could be made from `intab`, `outtab`:

```
char trantab[256]; // translation table
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
  trantab[i] = i; // initialize

while (*intab && *outtab)
  trantab[(unsigned char) *intab++] = *outtab++;
```